# How can I efficiently prove existential propositions with multiple variables in Isabelle/Isar?

Tags: isabelle, quantifiers, isar

Say I want to prove the lemma `∃ n m k . [n, m, k] = [2, 3, 5]` in Isabelle/Isar. If I go ahead as suggested in the Isabelle/HOL tutorial on page 45, my proof looks as follows:

```
lemma "∃ n m k . [n, m, k] = [2, 3, 5]"
proof
  show "∃ m k . [2, m, k] = [2, 3, 5]"
  proof
    show "∃ k . [2, 3, k] = [2, 3, 5]"
    proof
      show "[2, 3, 5] = [2, 3, 5]" by simp
    qed
  qed
qed
```

Of course, this is way too verbose. How can I prove propositions like the above one such that the proofs are concise and readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple existential quantifiers can be introduced in a single step by applying the single-quantifier introduction rule several times. For example, the proof method `(rule exI)+` introduces all outermost existential quantifiers.

```
lemma "∃n m k. [n, m, k] = [2, 3, 5]"
proof(rule exI)+
  show "[2, 3, 5] = [2, 3, 5]" by simp
qed
```

Alternatively, you can first state the instantiated property and then use an automatic proof method to do the instantiations. Usually `blast` works well here because it does not invoke the simplfier. In your example, you will have to add type annotations because numbers are overloaded.

```
lemma "∃n m k :: nat. [n, m, k] = [2, 3, 5]"
proof -
  have "[2, 3, 5 :: nat] = [2, 3, 5]" by simp
  then show ?thesis by blast
qed
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using `proof force` as suggested by Hira is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I especially like the second variant, as it gives very readable proofs.