# How can I prove the lemma in Exercise 4.6 in “Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL”?

Tags: isabelle, quantifiers, isar

I am trying to solve Exercise 4.6 in “Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL”. It asks to define a function `elems :: "'a list ⇒ 'a set"` that converts a list into a set, and to prove the lemma `"x ∈ elems xs ⟹ ∃ ys zs . xs = ys @ x # zs ∧ x ∉ elems ys"`. Until now, I have come that far:

```
fun elems :: "'a list ⇒ 'a set" where
  "elems [] = {}" |
  "elems (x # xs) = {x} ∪ elems xs"

lemma first_occ: "x ∈ elems xs ⟹ ∃ ys zs . xs = ys @ x # zs ∧ x ∉ elems ys"
proof (induction xs)
  case Nil
  thus ?case by simp
next
  case (Cons u us)
  show ?case
  proof cases
    assume "x = u"
    thus ?case
    proof
    ⟨…⟩
```

At this point, I get the error message “Failed to apply initial proof method”. This is strange, since the goal, `?case`, is the proposition `∃ ys zs . u # us = ys @ x # zs ∧ x ∉ elems ys`, and it should be possible to prove existential propositions by showing the proposition under the `∃` for a specific witness.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your line `proof` is that it `proof` is meant to apply some default rule. In the above proof, Isabelle is not able to figure out that you want to perform existential introduction. So, you probably want to explicitly tell the system to do so, e.g., by continue with something like `proof (intro exI)`.

I hope, this helps, 
René

Comment: Why can’t Isabelle figure this out? If the goal is a proposition of the form `∃ x . P`; so Isabelle should choose existential introduction automatically. It worked in other situations (for instance, in the example code in my question [“How can I efficiently prove existential propositions with multiple variables in Isabelle/Isar?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464404); why not here?

Comment: Because you also chained in a fact with `thus`. Proof methods like `rule` will only work if all the chained-in facts can be unified with the assumptions of the rule to apply in the correct order. If you don't supply a method explicitly, Isabelle will use `standard`, which is similar to `rule` with some default set of rules. TL;DR you rarely want to chain in facts into a `proof`. Use `show` instead of `thus` here.